# Retrieve old value from Laravel Form::select

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5

I have the following form field in a `Laravel` project in my `create view` (`create.blade.php`):

```php
{{ Form::label('format', 'Type', ['class'=>'label']) }}
{{ Form::select('format', array('is_html' => "HTML", 'is_video' => 'Video'), null, ['class' => 'form-control format']) }}
```

I retrieve this inside the `format` column in my database so i can use this data in my project.

Now, inside the `edit` (`edit.blade.php`) view I want to have the already selected data to reflect. So when the user has selected "video", the select option will already be set to `Video`.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to show the value posted in the form, or use value from DB for example ?

Answer (score 1):

While I was typing this question, i figured it out. Already typed the entire question so might as well post it to help someone out.

The `third argument` needs to correspond with the data I retrieve from the database. So, for example, if i wanted the `Video` to be selected, it would look like this:

```php
{{ Form::label('format', 'Type', ['class'=>'label']) }}
{{ Form::select('format', array('is_html' => "HTML", 'is_video' => 'Video'), 'is_video', ['class' => 'form-control format']) }}
```

I replaced the `is_video` with the variable that contains the data from my `database` and it's working as expected.

```php
{{ Form::label('format', 'Type', ['class'=>'label']) }}
{{ Form::select('format', array('is_html' => "HTML", 'is_video' => 'Video'), $var->format, ['class' => 'form-control format']) }}
```

Comment: *"I replaced the is_video with the variable"* - Might be more useful to others if you post that variable instead (something like `old('is_video')` I assume?) Right now, it's pointing towards hard-coding a value as the way to check, which isn't exactly right.

Comment: I clearly explain what's going on, right? Since the `var` never appears anywhere else in my question, it might be confusing to others if there is a `var` in there all of a sudden. So i clearly explain how to achieve it, then that i replace the hardcoded value with my `var` to get the result needed.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you explained it fine, but there's still the question of what `$var->format` contains, and how it handles form submission. Am I right that `$var->format` contains the result of `old('is_video', '')` (or something similar)? Or is it something else?

Comment: When the initial form gets submitted, it send the corresponding data to the `format` column. So, if a video is selected, it send the string `is_video` to the database that get's stored inside the `format` column used on an instance of a `Class`. The `Class` I use is `chapter`, so the `var` in this case will be `$chapter->format`.

Comment: Ah ok, so there's only 2 options, and you're not really worried about `old()` (which is present when the form is submitted and redirects after failed validation, etc), you're just worried about the value already present. I understand now. Generally, you'd do that by `old('format', $record->format)`, which would set the selected `option` to what's in the database record, or what was selected in the case of an invalidation redirect.